# MS Access - Report to PDF - Data fields not populating in controls on PDF

Tags: forms, ms-access, pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf file, based on the contents of an Access Form or a Report (either is fine for me but understand it should be done via a report).

I can generate/populate the form itself, and the report itself, but when I create the pdf with this code, the fields in the pdf are blank.  The controls are all there, like seen in my form, but the fields that should have data don't get copied over.

This works as-is for me, and makes a pdf that looks just like my report, except the data from the report does not carry over to the saved pdf

```
Private Sub pdfBtn_Click()

Dim fileName As String, fldrPath As String, filePath As String
  Dim answer As Integer

  fileName = "File_Test1" 'filename for PDF file*
  fldrPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop" 'folder path where pdf file will be saved *

  filePath = fldrPath & "\" & fileName & ".pdf"

  'check if file already exists
  If FileExist(filePath) Then
    answer = MsgBox(prompt:="PDF file already exists: " & vbNewLine & filePath & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Would you like to replace existing file?", buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Existing PDF File")
    If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo invalidFolderPath
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Report2", acFormatPDF, filePath

  MsgBox prompt:="PDF File exported to: " & vbNewLine & filePath, buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Report Exported as PDF"
  Exit Sub

invalidFolderPath:
  MsgBox prompt:="Error: Invalid folder path. Please update code.", buttons:=vbCritical

End Sub


Function FileExist(FileFullPath As String) As Boolean
  Dim value As Boolean
  value = False
  If Dir(FileFullPath) <> "" Then
    value = True
  End If
  FileExist = value
End Function
```

I've spent a few hours searching, so I'd be upset if it is something overly simple and available.  But is anyone able to point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. Suggest you test output method with a very simple report, no calculated fields, no subreports, no sorting/grouping/filter. Just run the OutputTo command from VBA immediate window.

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to ask for clarification - are you saying that the PDF saves for you, WITH data in the control/cells?  Or are  you just saying the PDF itself pops up/saves on the desktop?       I too am able to get it to save a pdf, but it is essentially blank.  It shows where the data should go, just nothing in them.    I will apply your suggestion now, thank you for your time and energy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had some logic wrong.  Yes the code provided does work, thanks again @June7.  I was over complicating things by trying to generate the pdf off the form itself, versus off a report.  I ended up making the button pop up the report instead of another form, and the data does now flow as expected.

Silly, like I said :(